# Regex pattern fails to match in python

Tags: python-3.x, regex

The following regex pattern fails to match as I would expect it would do.

The text fragment is:

```
txt = 'ΠΡΟΣ:  ΚΟΙΝ. :     Αθήνα,  16 - 10 - 2013  Αριθµ. Πρωτ. :  Κ2 – 6376 (δις)   ΤΟ ΕΘΝΙΚΟ ΤΥΠΟΓΡΑΦΕΙΟ  Καποδιστρίου 34  104 32 ΑΘΗΝΑ   Συνηµ. : ∆ιπλότ. Νο Η 3833967/2013      «ΚΥΠΡΟΥ ΑΕ∆ΑΚ»    Φειδιππίδου 26 & Χαλκηδόνος   11527  ΑΘΗΝΑ   ΑΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ  Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εµπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της ανώνυµης εταιρείας µε την επωνυµία  «ΚΥΠΡΟΥ ASSET MANAGEMENT ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ∆ΙΑΧΕΙΡΙΣΕΩΣ ΑΜΟΙΒΑΙΩΝ ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΩΝ».  Ο ΥΦΥΠΟΥΡΓΟΣ ΑΝΑΠΤΥΞΗΣ  ΚΑΙ   ΑΝΤΑΓΩΝΙΣΤΙΚΟΤΗΤΑΣ  '
```

The regex pattern is:

```
import re
epwnymia_pattern = re.compile(r'επωνυμία\s+«([\(?\w+\s*\)?]+)»')
epwnymia = epwnymia_pattern.search(txt).group(1)  # Fails
```

I would expect to match the following phrase:

```
ΚΥΠΡΟΥ ASSET MANAGEMENT ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ∆ΙΑΧΕΙΡΙΣΕΩΣ ΑΜΟΙΒΑΙΩΝ ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΩΝ
```

What is the reason the regex fails and how I should correct it?

Comment: You need the `re.IGNORECASE` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me the easiest way to match that string is by using a negated character class `[^«»]` (that matches any char but `«` and `»`) **and** you need case insensitive matching:

```
(?i)επωνυμία\s+«([^«»]+)»
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ZQLth/1)

Also, when you want to get the first match with `re.search`, it make sense to first check if there was a match at all before accessing the Group 1 value:

```
import re
txt = r'ΠΡΟΣ:  ΚΟΙΝ. :     Αθήνα,  16 - 10 - 2013  Αριθµ. Πρωτ. :  Κ2 – 6376 (δις)   ΤΟ ΕΘΝΙΚΟ ΤΥΠΟΓΡΑΦΕΙΟ  Καποδιστρίου 34  104 32 ΑΘΗΝΑ   Συνηµ. : ∆ιπλότ. Νο Η 3833967/2013      «ΚΥΠΡΟΥ ΑΕ∆ΑΚ»    Φειδιππίδου 26 & Χαλκηδόνος   11527  ΑΘΗΝΑ   ΑΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ  Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εµπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της ανώνυµης εταιρείας µε την επωνυµία  «ΚΥΠΡΟΥ ASSET MANAGEMENT ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ∆ΙΑΧΕΙΡΙΣΕΩΣ ΑΜΟΙΒΑΙΩΝ ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΩΝ».  Ο ΥΦΥΠΟΥΡΓΟΣ ΑΝΑΠΤΥΞΗΣ  ΚΑΙ   ΑΝΤΑΓΩΝΙΣΤΙΚΟΤΗΤΑΣ  '
epwnymia_pattern = re.compile(r'(?i)επωνυμία\s+«([^«»]+)»')
epwnymia = epwnymia_pattern.search(txt)
if epwnymia:
    print(epwnymia.group(1))
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/9jvslJ), output:

```
ΚΥΠΡΟΥ ASSET MANAGEMENT ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ∆ΙΑΧΕΙΡΙΣΕΩΣ ΑΜΟΙΒΑΙΩΝ ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΩΝ
```